# Copy work very well, while Move doesnt work at all.

Tags: windows, perl, command-line, permissions

```
use File::Copy;


#Variable with my directory I work on
$dir = "C:/projekty/perl/muzyka";

#Variables used to find all mp3 files
$dir_tmp = $dir."/*.mp3";
@files = glob( $dir_tmp );

#Variable with directory I want to create and put my files to
$new_dir = "C:/projekty/perl/muzyka/new_dir";

#Creating new directory
mkdir ( $new_dir ) or print "MKDIR PROBLEM";
```

Till this point everything is allright. Now I put the loop:

```
foreach( @pliki )
{   
    copy( $_, $new_dir) or print "COPY PROBLEM";
}
```

or:

```
foreach( @pliki )
{   
    move( $_, $new_dir) or print "MOVE PROBLEM";
}
```

And the problem is: Copy works perfectly fine, but Move doesn't want to do its job. It works sometimes depends on some modifications in code but never in a loop. Simple code with 1 line:

```
move($a, $b);
```

works perfectly. But if I use some conditions or loops it stops working even if arguments (directories) seem OK (I checked them with print function put in a loop). Why is it not working? Are there any circumstances that would cause errors?

Comment: does `print "MOVE PROBLEM: $!"` help to get more details?

Comment: Didn't think about it! Teacher said this var is veeeeery helpful and I forgot. It says "Permission denied". How can I give the permission?

Comment: `chmod` is used to change permissions, and `chown` is used to change user and group ownership. They are both command-line utitilies, Perl functions and system calls.

Comment: Im working with Windows. I've already changed attributes but it didn't help.

Comment: Try moving the same files with windows `move/?` from command line.

Comment: And I found it out. I need to close the file BEFORE I want to move it. Thanks for help!

Comment: @glebogryzacz: You didn't indicate in any way that you were opening these files. How are we supposed to help you?

Comment: Yes, I know. I tottally forgot about it. Anyway You've helped with $! var. It helped

Answer (score 0):

`copy` and `move` are documented to set `$!` on error. It's also good to check whether the arguments are what you expect them to be. Pay particular attention to the presence of newlines and trailing spaces.

```
move($_, $new_dir)
   or warn("Can't move \"$_\" to \"$new_dir\": $!\n");
```